# Discoloured white chocolate chips

Tags: color, muffins

When baking rasberry and white chocolate muffins, the chocolate chips come out brown and discoloured on top and white in the middle. The taste of them is not affected. Does anyone have any (hopefully simple) solutions to make sure they come out nice and white. Also, the muffins were not overcooked, they came out nicely baked, fluffy on inside, not burnt anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried changing the brand of the chocolate chips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very easy fix.  If you simply coat the chips in flour before adding them to the mix, and then gently fold them in, you should get no discoloration, and the chips will stay suspended and not settle to the bottom.  For gluten-free recipes, coating with 10x powdered sugar will also work, as it contains cornstarch.  The trick is coating the sugar-containing items with starch of some kind.